# Extracting Price Information from IKEA website

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to extract the price information for a number of products on the IKEA website.

For each item, I have the URL and using  Google Spreadsheets I would like to extract the price of each item.

For example, in A1 I have http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/80236363/, and I would like to extract £1.35 and have this captured in A2.

Comment: It's helpful if you include what you have tried on your own in your post.  That way, someone can help you over the specific stumbling blocks you've encountered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use importxml to do this:

In cell A2 enter:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@class='packagePrice']")
```

[image]